# Putting Hex into a byte array

Tags: c, arrays, hex

I am trying to put hex values into a `Byte[]`, Trying to achieve 78,66,1E,B5,4F,E7,67,63

```
   #define BYTE   unsigned char
   int num = 1;

   long long hex[]
   {
     0x78661EB54FE76763,
   };

 int main()
 {

        for (int c = 0; c < num; c++)
        {
            printf("%llx\n", hex[c]);

            unsigned int number = hex[c];
            unsigned int ef = number & 0xff;
            unsigned int cd = (number >> 8) & 0xff;
            unsigned int ab = (number >> 16) & 0xff;

            printf("%x", number & 0xff);

            BYTE data2[8]{
                ef, cd, ab
            };

        }
}
```

**Update:**

Basically I have an array of 30 odd hex values. I am trying to loop through that array called hex[], then for each hex value separate it into 2's ie 78,66,1E,B5,4F,E7,67,63 then add each one into an array of type BYTE which will hold the hex value in 8 pairs so data[0] will have the value of 78 up to data[8] which will have the value of 63, So I can then pass the array of type BYTE to another method for further work

Comment: This will not compile as is.  Because `long long hex[]` is a declaration with initializers, the statement requires an `=` sign before the first curly: `{`, and a C statement terminator: `;` after the closing curly: `}`.  And the comma after `0x78661EB54FE76763` should be removed.

Comment: will compile for you now, updated

Comment: you keep saying "basically I have an array of 30 odd hex values.". What do you mean, your sample shows one long long with one big value. What is your real starting data, show it in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution that you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    long long hex=0x78661EB54FE76763;
    BYTE val[8];

    for(j=0,i=7; i>=0; i--,j++){
        val[j]= (hex>>(i*8))&0xff;
    }       

    printf("Hexadecimal bytes are:\n");
    for(j=0;j<8;j++){
        printf("%02X ",val[j]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

And the output is:

```
Hexadecimal bytes are:
78 66 1E B5 4F E7 67 63
```

Comment: I think OP wants to break a big number into little numbers.  You are initializing with little numbers.

Comment: basically I have an array of 30 odd hex values. I am trying to loop through that array called hex[],  then for each hex value separate it into 2's ie  78,66,1E,B5,4F,E7,67,63 then add each one into an array of type BYTE  which will hold the  hex value in 8 pairs so  data[0] will have the value of 78

Comment: Had the value been `long long hex=0x78661EB54FE76763 | 0x8000000000000000;`, the right shift of the sign bit leads to "value is implementation-defined" C11 §6.5.7 5 .  Better to use `unsigned long long hex`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `BYTE` is a type

```
BYTE data2[] = {ef, cd, ab, '\0'};
```

Use the `null` terminator to allow printing with `"%s"` and `printf()`.

Of course, you can add the rest of the bytes.

Comment: Yes BYTE is a type, I updated above, sorry if I am explaining this is a confusing way. I just cant figure out how to add them in pairs on two in simple terms

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple task to accomplish all you need is the initialization values that you have given. 
 `long long hex[] = { 0x78661EB54FE76763 };`

Next, you need a char pointer that is pointing to the hex array 
`unsigned char* pByte = (unsigned char*)hex;  // Point to the first element in hex array`

Then create an 8 byte buffer and clear it with memset:

`unsigned char byteArray[8];`
`memset(byteArray, 0, sizeof(byteArray));`

All you need to do now is dereference your char pointer and place the value into your 8 byte buffer.

```
// Loop through the hex array and assign the current byte
// the byte pointer is pointing to then increment the byte pointer
// to look at the next value.
// This for loop is for a system that is little endian (i.e. win32)
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
  byteArray[i] = *pByte;
  pByte++;  
}
```

**Note:**  Since I ran this with Visual Studio 2015 everything is little endian.  This is why the first for loop is written the way it is.

See below for the full program listing I wrote & tested below demonstrating this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  long long hex[] = { 0x78661EB54FE76763 };    // Value of an element
  unsigned char* pByte = (unsigned char*)hex;  // Assign a char pointer to point to the first element in hex array
  unsigned char byteArray[8];                  // This is the byte buffer that will be populated from the hex array
  memset(byteArray, 0, sizeof(byteArray));     // Clear out the memory of byte array before filling in the indices

  // Loop through the hex array and assign the current byte
  // the byte pointer is pointing to then increment the byte pointer
  // to look at the next value.
  // This for loop is for a system that is little endian (i.e. win32)
  for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    byteArray[i] = *pByte;  // Dereference the pointer and assign value to buffer
    pByte++;                // Point to the next byte
  }

  // Print the byte array
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    printf("The value of element %i is: %X\n", i, byteArray[i]);
  }

  printf("Press any key to continue...");   // Hold the console window open
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you "clear it with memset" when you just overwrite the whole array in the next loop anyway

Comment: I like to initialize everything to a defined state to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: using `= { 0 };` instead of memset reduces the risk of UB due to making a mistake with memset

Comment: I am aware of this syntax but it is not guaranteed on all platforms especially if you have a union as part of the struct.  Where as memset is guaranteed and it get optimized quite well plus it is a little more verbose.  I have done it both ways but I prefer to use memset.